# Foreigner returned home from US in May. How to handle US taxes?

Tags: united-states, taxes

I am a foreigner who has lived in the US for a long time, long enough to be taxed as a resident (to clarify, I was never a Permanent Resident). I moved home permanently last May. I couldn't find any instructions online or in the IRS FAQ on whether or how I have to file US taxes. Any help?

Comment: If you have permanent residence you're taxed wherever you are--you still have to file even if you're living elsewhere.  You report your total income but you get a credit for whatever tax you paid to where you're living now.

Comment: @Loren Pechtel I was never a permanent resident of the US. Edited question to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the question is whether you are a resident alien or nonresident alien for 2016. I believe you satisfy the Substantial Presence Test, because although you don't have 183 days in 2016, when you add 1/3 of the days from 2015 and 1/6 of the days from 2014, that probably exceeds 183 days. However, since you had less than 183 days in 2016, if you can establish "[closer connection to a foreign country](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/conditions-for-a-closer-connection-to-a-foreign-country)", you can be considered a nonresident for 2016.

Comment: Thanks. I think I clearly am a nonresident based on that "closer connection to foreign country", and then the rules on whether nonresident aliens have to file a tax return are given on this page: https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/taxation-of-nonresident-aliens